# Magento SQL query from model

Tags: php, mysql, magento

inWHen I run this SQL query, I get result:

```
SELECT `productId`, `title`, `description`, `imageUrlStr`, `mrp`, `price`, `productUrl`, `categories`, `productBrand`, `deliveryTime`, `inStock`, `codAvailable`, `emiAvailable`, `offers`, `discount`, `cashBack`, `size`, `color`, `sizeUnit`, `sizeVariants`, `colorVariants` FROM `homeliv`.`table_furniture` WHERE productId in ('SOFE94HW8TPTGPNX','BDDE9EKAZ2GZZJGN') LIMIT 100
```

However, when I run this in Magento, I get two rows but the result is empty.

```
$products = Mage::getModel("similar/table")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('productId',array('in' => $ids));
 foreach ($products as $p){
        Mage::log("Id====>".$p->getProductId());
        Mage::log("ImageSrc=====>".$p->getImageUrlStr());
        Mage::log("Product Url====>".$p->getProductUrl());
        Mage::log("Product Url==========================================================>");
    }
```

This I am getting in the log file:

```
Id====>
2016-03-29T11:08:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): ImageSrc=====>
2016-03-29T11:08:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Product Url====>
2016-03-29T11:08:35+00:00 DEBUG (7):==========================================================>
2016-03-29T11:08:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Id====>
2016-03-29T11:08:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): ImageSrc=====>
2016-03-29T11:08:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Product Url====>
2016-03-29T11:08:35+00:00 DEBUG (7):==========================================================>
```

My primary id is string, and the ids array is an array of string in the question. The query being printed from magento is

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `flipkart_furniture` AS `main_table` WHERE (productId IN('SOFE94HW8TPTGPNX', 'SOFE94HW5FE4EXQM', 'BDDE9EKAZ2GZZJGN', 'BDDEBB94DHWXAMFC')) which gives result in mysql. Don't know what is wrong here
```

Comment: is my get method correct, I am using getProductId(). Is it correct?

Comment: Because when I do getPrice(), it works fine, only where camelcase wordings are used, it casuses problem. I cant change column name, as i am importing from external resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

->getData('productId') is the way to go